# Haskell: Why is there no type mismatch (and why does this compile)?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, typeclass, ghci

I was so sleepy that I wrote the following code (modified to just show the confusion):

```
fac s = take 10 [s, s `mod` 1 ..]

maxFactor x = if (s == [])
              then x
              else head    <-- this should be 'head x' instead of just 'head'
  where s = fac x
```

However, this load into ghci (and compiles) just fine. When I executed `maxFactor 1`, it complains (of course):

```
<interactive>:0:1:
    No instance for (Integral ([a0] -> a0))
      arising from a use of `maxFactor'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Integral ([a0] -> a0))
    In the expression: maxFactor 1
    In an equation for `it': it = maxFactor 1

<interactive>:0:11:
    No instance for (Num ([a0] -> a0))
      arising from the literal `1'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num ([a0] -> a0))
    In the first argument of `maxFactor', namely `1'
    In the expression: maxFactor 1
    In an equation for `it': it = maxFactor 1
```

However, I don't understand this behavior:

`fac`'s type is:

```
fac :: Integral a => a -> [a]
```

while `maxFactor`'s type is:

```
maxFactor :: Integral ([a] -> a) => ([a] -> a) -> [a] -> a
```

Doesn't this mean the following:

1. the first input to `fac` must be of typeclass `Integral` (e.g., `fac 10`);
2. since in the definition of `maxFactor`, there is `fac x`, x must also be of typeclass `Integral`, thus, `maxFactor`'s type would be begin with something like `maxFactor :: (Integral a) => a ->`... then something else? However, if that is the case, then why this code compiles since the return of `maxFactor` can be `x` or `head`, which when following this line of reasoning, does not have the same type?

What am I missing here?

Thanks for any inputs in advance!

Comment: This kind of issue can arise in a much simpler manner. I suspect (but I am no expert) that it can happen whenever the type checker cannot reduce an expression sufficiently. For instance, foo x = 1 + x; bar = foo head -- will fail, but foo x = 1 + x; bar x = foo head -- will compile.

Comment: @Sarah: The example you provide doesn't typecheck because of monomorphism restriction; if you add pragma, it typechecks (there's subtle problem though: GHCi infers type `Num ([a] → a) ⇒ [a] → a` and you cannot declare `bar` with this type, you'd need FlexibleContexts for that).

Comment: For what it's worth, if you compile with `-Wall` (or add that to your default ghci options, so that ghci "compiles" with `-Wall`) you'll get a warning because you didn't put a type signature on `maxFactor`. Then, presumably, you'll write `maxFactor :: Integral a => a -> a` and it will fail to compile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in `maxFactor` the compiler infers that the function argument `x` necessarily has the same type as `head` (in your `if` clause). Since you also call `fac` on `x` (which in turn calls `mod`) it infers that `x` is also some `Integral` class type. Consequently, the compiler infers the type

```
maxFactor :: Integral ([a] -> a) => ([a] -> a) -> [a] -> a
```

that takes some `head`-like and integer-like argument... which is unlikely to be a real thing.

<strike>I think the fact that you can load that code into GHCi is more a quirk of the interpreter. If you were just compiling the code above, it would fail.</strike>

Edit: I guess the issue is that the type checker can make sense of your code, however there probably isn't any sensible way to use it.

Comment: Actually it could compile (My version is 7.2.1) :( Is this a bug in GHC now? I wonder... But still, thanks!

Comment: @ZiyaoWei not if you try to add those inferred type declarations.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei: It's not a bug. GHC can't know there will never be a function `[a]->a` that is an instance of `Integral`.

Comment: Looks fishy to me, too. Of course, you could never actually _use_ it in your compiled program.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Could I define a function to be typeclass `Integral` or maybe just Haskell's type system is not power enough here? Thanks for the great explanation!

Comment: @ZiyaoWei: yes, you could define a function to be a typeclass instance. It would just probably not be a good idea. — Haskell's type system is powerful enough, it just doesn't _predict_ every ridiculous thing the programmer might do in the future.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei If you want a function to be of class `Integral` just do it: `instance Integral ([a]->a)` (you'll need FlexibleInstances to compile it).  You'll also have to make it and instance of `Num`.  Exactly what you want the methods to do, well, I'll leave that to you.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Thanks! I know I was being ridiculous:)

Comment: @augustss: Thanks for FlexibleInstances! I'll probably correct my error before defining such a cute function in the program:)

Comment: @augustss I think there actually is a semi-sane way to make that type a number. Basically, `fromInteger = flip genericIndex` and `toInteger = ($ [0..])`, then everything else follows from them.

Answer (score 11):

As you've noticed correctly, the use of function `fac` inside of `maxFactor` adds a `Integral a` constraint on the type of `x`. So `x` needs to be of type `Integral a => a`.

In addition, the compiler sees that `maxFactor` either returns `head`, which has type `[a]->a` or `x`. Therefore `x` must have the more specific type `Integral ([a]->a) => ([a]->a)`, and so `maxFactor` has type

```
maxFactor :: Integral ([a] -> a) => ([a] -> a) -> ([a] -> a)
```

which is exactly what you got. There's nothing "wrong" with this definition so far.  If you managed to write an instance of `Integral` type `([a]->a)` you could invoke `maxFactor` without problem. (Obviously `maxFactor` wouldn't work as expected.)